# Import custom component as script Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently trying to use a custom component (https://github.com/wolfika/vue-playing-card) in my demo application built with Vue CLI.

First I've tried in a JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/xwb59m8g/1/) and everything works as expected just by importing the `<script>` (as explained in the Github "Browser" section) and using the `<vue-playing-card>` custom component. Than I've tried including the component in my Vue CLI app by following the instruction on the Github page under the "Bundler (Webpack, Rollup)" section and everything works.

My problem is that, for some reasons that I will explain if you need to know, I have to include this component using the `<script>` tag, as in the JS Fiddle, and not with the "Bundler (Webpack, Rollup)".
I tried including the `<script>` tag at the bottom of my index.html file but when I try to include the custom component in my Vue application this error gets printed in the console:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? etc.

I really don't understand what it's happening since in the JS Fiddle everthing works as expected... can you help me? Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've tried and searched all I could.